# Is it possible to change max timestamp in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have a series `StartDate` that holds dates in a Dataframe,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'StartDate':['1/1/2100','1/12/2500']})
```

It overlaps the max timestamp of pandas `Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807')`

For example: `'1/1/2100'`

Is there a way maybe changing the max timestamp to a bigger value?

By using `df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate']).dt.date` I'm getting `'Nat'` and not `'1/1/2100'`

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to change max timestamp in pandas?

I think not.

---

You can convert dates to [daily periods](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#representing-out-of-bounds-spans):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'StartDate':['1/1/2100','1/12/2500']})

df['StartDate'] = df['StartDate'].apply(lambda x: pd.Period(x, freq="D"))
print (df)
    StartDate
0  2100-01-01
1  2500-01-12
```

Unfortunately if convert values to `datetime`s in pure python ouput is object, not timestamps:

```
import datetime as dt

df['StartDate'] = df['StartDate'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x,"%m/%d/%Y"))
print (df)
             StartDate
0  2100-01-01 00:00:00
1  2500-01-12 00:00:00

print (df.dtypes)
StartDate    object
dtype: object
```

EDIT: If there are not missing values use `errors='coerce'` parameter for `NaT` for not possible convert datetimes and replace them in `fillna` by maximum `Timestamp`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'StartDate':['1/1/2100','1/12/2500']})

df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate'], errors='coerce').fillna(pd.Timestamp.max)
print (df)
                      StartDate
0 2100-01-01 00:00:00.000000000
1 2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807
```

If possible NaNs in input data is necessary set values by masks:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'StartDate':['1/1/2100','1/12/2500', np.nan]})

m1 = df['StartDate'].notna()
s = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate'], errors='coerce')
m2 = s.isna()
df['StartDate'] = s.mask(m1 & m2, pd.Timestamp.max)
print (df)
                      StartDate
0 2100-01-01 00:00:00.000000000
1 2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807
2                           NaT
```

Comment: Execution time takes forever.

Comment: @Moshe - Ya, and then working with it is not easy. Beause `Period` is not `Timestamp` :(

Comment: What about setting each timestamp greater than the max, to the max, possible ?

Comment: @Moshe - are missing values in datetimes?

Comment: @Moshe - Added solution to answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is not directly possible, because internally Pandas uses the numpy `datatime64[ns]` type, said differently an 64 bits integer number of nanoseconds since the Epoch (1/01/1970).

So you will be left with only workarounds.

1. Forget about vectorization and directly use native Python types:

   ```
    df['StartDate'] = df['StartDate'].apply(
        lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y').date())
   ```

   but that will be sub optimal for large arrays because Python dates will be handled as an object column.
2. Use numpy datetime64 type, because numpy accept other units than ns. Unfortunately, you will have to use `datetime` or `dateutil` for the conversion because numpy only accept ISO 8601 format (`2500-12-01`):

   ```
    df['StartDate'] = np.datetime64(df['StartDate'].apply(
        lambda x: np.datetime64(dateutil.parser.parse(x), 'ms'))
   ```

   Here again you will get an object column, but at least numpy will be able to use it in a vectorized way.

Comment: Although numpy use it in a vectorized way, it is still not efficient enough in terms of execution time on large arrays.

Comment: It cannot be efficient, because the conversion uses a Python function and not a numpy ufunc... Unfortunately, Pandas only uses nano-seconds...